# Import error while using dev_appserver.py in virtualenv

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv

When I run `dev_appserver.py .` (in the directory containing the `app.py`) while being in an virtualenv with Python 2.7.12, I get this error and output:

```
(.venv)$ dev_appserver.py .                                                              
INFO     2017-02-21 18:54:47,250 devappserver2.py:764] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-02-21 18:54:47,273 api_server.py:268] Starting API server at: http://localhost:35473
INFO     2017-02-21 18:54:47,276 dispatcher.py:199] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-02-21 18:54:47,276 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py", line 101, in <module>
_run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/opt/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py", line 97, in _run_file
execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/opt/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py", line 185, in <module>
main()
  File "/opt/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py", line 165, in main
sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)
  File "/opt/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 198, in enable_sandbox
__import__('%s.threading' % dist27.__name__)
  File "/opt/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/threading.py", line 11, in <module>
import warnings
  File "/opt/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 1001, in load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named warnings
```

Works fine when I'm not in the virtualenv. The `warnings` module is part of the python standard library as I understand it, so not sure what to to do here. Running `pip install warnings` doesn't help.

How do I get dev_appserver.py to run in the virtualenv?

Comment: In your `.venv/lib/python2.7` directory, is there a symlink for `warnings.py`

Comment: @haeger were you able to solve this issue ? I am also stuck with same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not working with dev_appserver.py and virtualenv in a proper way. Virtualenv is not to be used here. Relevant documentation on using third-party libraries is found [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27?authuser=1).

---

In short, to include third party libraries with dev_appserver.py:

Instruct pip to store libraries in a folder with the `-t` flag:

```
$ pip install -t lib/ <library name>
```

Create a file named `appengine_config.py` in the same folder as `app`, and include the following code:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Now run dev_appserver.py as usual: `$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

---

Keep in mind that you can only use Python libraries that use pure Python code (e.g. the `bcrypt` library cannot be used.).

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that the official documentation suggests that one uses a virtualenv. Even the link you gave suggests that a virtualenv can be used